# Twilio Alphanumeric Sender ID not working using Java

Tags: java, sms, twilio, alphanumeric

I am not able to change the alphanumeric sender ID in twilio using java. I already changed the "From" parameter and set it to "MyCompany" but still it doesn't work. As well as using the Message servive ID or the Copilot feature in Twilio to manually set the Alphanumeric Sender ID but still I keep on receiving "INFO" as the sender ID when I send a message.

This is my code:

```
Message message = Message.creator(
            new PhoneNumber("+63XXXXXXXXX"), //To
            new PhoneNumber("MyCompany"), //From
            "Hello World" //Body
        ).create();
```

Using the above code will return this error below:

```
The 'To' phone number: +63XXXXXXXXX, is not currently reachable using the 'From' phone number: MyCompany via SMS
```

but changing the "MyCompany" with my Twilio number will send the sms successfully.

The documentation shows that you only need to change the "From" parameter to something like you business name or company name (ex. "MyCompany")

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You're trying to send a message to a number in the Philippines (+63). While Twilio supports sender alphanumeric sender IDs when sending to the Philippines you are [required to pre-register the sender ID](https://www.twilio.com/sms/guidelines/ph).

To start the process of registering your sender ID, please get in contact with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact).

Comment: Can't find a way to use sender id in java sdk. I have registered.

Comment: @NikhilSharma, I see you are in India, if you are trying to send using an alphanumeric sender ID to an Indian number then you need to pre-register the sender ID itself. Get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and they will take you through the process.

Comment: I informed that I have done the registration of sender id.

Comment: I just left the `from` parameter and it used the default sender id. When sender id is not present it will use the fallback number. Thanks